# Key from OEM partition to be used on HDD

Tags: windows, oem

Maybe the title is not that good, but I did not know how to describe my problem in a few words.

On my laptop, beside the HDD, I have an 24gb SSHD which is an OEM partition with Windows 8 Pro and I want to replace it with a 3g modem (my model allows this).
The thing is, I installed an unactivated copy of Windows 8.1 on my HDD and it activated with the key from the SSHD (I don't know how). Since I want to remove the SSHD, I managed to find out the key with a the help of ProduKey, but the things is, when I'll do a clean reinstall of 8.1 on the HDD, will I be able to activate it with the key found through ProduKey?

From experience I know that the produces usually activate a lot of laptops with one key and provides you, the customer, with another (your paid copy) via a sticker on the bottom of your laptop - the things is mine doesn't have that sticker.

Comment: You should have no problems in activating using that key from the BIOS/UEFI. If at all you do, just use phone activation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you **Karan**, I self-answered my question with the info from your comment!

I didn't knew that since Windows 8 the key is saved in the BIOS (UEFI). The key that I extracted from the *BIOS* is identical with the one found with *ProduKey*. From my recent research, I found out that the BIOS key is the equivalent of the one found on the bottom-sticker.

Thank you again!